# See AMD Catalyst driver versions via command line

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, amd-catalyst

Using the command line in Xubuntu 11.04, how can I see which version of the AMD Catalyst driver are currently installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the log at /var/log/Xorg.0.log to see which driver is being loaded. For example:

```
[    11.865] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,...

[    11.865] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    11.865] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    11.865] (++) using VT number 7

[    11.866] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
```

You can also use the **lspci -v** command and look for VGA Controller.